# simplexml_load_file failed to open stream: Connection timed out

Tags: php, xml

This page of my site is taking 1 minute to load. Then I got this error:

> "Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(http://www.cpalead.com/dashboard/reports/campaign_rss.php?id=MyID&geoip=MyIP&show=6&offer_type=pinsubmit):
>   failed to open stream: Connection timed out in ../pass/pass.php on
>   line 125 Warning: simplexml_load_file()"

My code:

```
$call_url = 'http://www.cpalead.com/dashboard/reports/campaign_rss.php?id='.$user_id.'&geoip='.$ip.'&show=6'.'&offer_type=pinsubmit';
if($xml = simplexml_load_file($call_url, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA))
```

What I've tried to fix that and didn't work:

- Switch allow_url_fopen to ON in php.ini of my hosting.
- set the max time out to 300 second instead of 120.

Comment: For me, it worked without error.

Comment: Make sure, your IP is not blocked for that site.

Comment: It work for me also when I navigate the generated url.

Comment: But it worked for me with the php code you have added. Is the error in your localhost or server?

Comment: on a hosting server.

Comment: In that case, I guess, the website has blocked the IP of your hosting server. Try `file_get_contenst($call_url)` to see if that gets anything.

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: I told you to try to make sure it doesn't work! ;) So, it's sure that your server cannot access the site. (which means it's blocked by that site for any reason!).

Comment: the code was working few hours ago, only now I get this error without any modification.

Comment: Here you go! Now it's obvious that the site has blocked your server, after they got too many requests from your server.

Comment: So what the solution?

Comment: No solution until they unblock you voluntarily or upon your request (I am not sure they have a way to do that). But if you can move to another server, that can work, until they block that server also! (Golden rule is "Don't make too many requests to any specific site unless they have allowed you to do that by terms").

Comment: That's the problem my server has been blocked, thanks Tareq Mahmoud :)

Comment: I have posted an answer summarizing the above discussion, pls accept the answer, so that others can consider the issue fixed and some others can get help with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the website has blocked your server, after they got too many requests from your server.

There is no solution until they unblock you voluntarily or upon your request (I am not sure they have a way to do that). But if you can move to another server, that can work, until they block that server also!

> Golden rule is *"Don't make too many requests to any specific site unless they have allowed you to do that by terms."*

Comment: That's right, but who blocked who? I switched to another cpa api but the same problem!

Comment: `cpalead.com` has blocked your hosting server. So no api should work until they unblock the server.

Comment: I switched to Cpagrip.com but the same problem!

Comment: Hm. Looks like cpagrip has blocked it for all. Because I cannot access it too. And I don't think the blocking is from your server side. You can confirm that just by `file_get_contents('http://google.com/')`. (Don't try it too many times, the browser will suspect it as a phishing attempt.)

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 3 to be resource, integer given in ../pass/pass.php on line 108 error fetching xml offer feed.

Comment: don't put anything in parameter 3. only using the first parameter will work. The others are optional.

Comment: Can you please write me what to put using the above code?

Comment: Then try it this way, `$call_url = 'http://google.com';
echo file_get_contents($call_url);`

Comment: Anyways, If you are still confused with the reason. Pls unaccept the answer and the others can also help. I told you to accept the answer, because I thought you found the issue correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing! Pls **unaccept** the answer if it doesn't help. Others may help you!